# What happens when I convert a Date type object to numeric, in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a vector containing some dates :

```
MyDates<-structure(c(16406, 16407, 16408, 16411, 16416, 16417, 16421, 
                     16423, 16424), class = "Date")
```

I coerced them to numeric

```
MyDatesInNumbers<-as.numeric(MyDates)
```

And very obviously, I got the below output :

```
> MyDatesInNumbers
[1] 16406 16407 16408 16411 16416 16417 16421 16423 16424
```

What exactly is happening inside and what is the meaning of those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the number of days after 1970.01.01...

See:

```
MyDates<-structure(c(0, 1, 2, 16411, 16416, 16417, 16421, 16423, 16424), class = "Date")
MyDates
[1] "1970-01-01" "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "2014-12-07" "2014-12-12" "2014-12-13" "2014-12-17" "2014-12-19" "2014-12-20"
```

Maybe some more background on [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)